# Jquery doesn't insert literally CDATA from XML inside html

Tags: jquery, html, xml, parsing, cdata

I've been searching for a similar question to avoid asking already solved questions, but I haven't found a valid answer for me, sorry if there's one and I haven't seen it. 
I'm reading an XML file from Jquery, the xml file has some CDATA stuff that I have purposely added and that I would like to preserve for formatting purposes:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<categories>
    <description name="whatever">
        Blah, blah, blah<![CDATA[<br />]]>blah, blah, blah
    </description>
</categories>
```

After reading it, I append it to a div:

```
$(xml).find('description[name="whatever"]').each(function()
{       
    $(container).append($(this));
});
```

What I've got is that Jquery seems to scape the '<' and '>' so I finally have:

```
Blah, blah, blah&l;tbr /&gt;blah, blah, blah
```

I have already tried to force the appending to treat the content as text like this:

```
$(container).text($(this));
```

But then I get:

```
[Object object]
```

And if I do .html() I get the same result as with the .append()...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the folks that may fall in the same hole in the future:

First of all, declare it as XML:

```
$.get("yourxml.xml", {}, function (data) 
{            

},'xml');
```

Afterwards, introduce it like text:

```
$(xml).find('description[name="whatever"]').each(function()
{       
    $(container).append($(this).text());
});
```

This is working for me like a charm!

Comment: If it's supposed to be HTML, you should be using `.html()`... :-?

Answer (score 2):

Ordinary XML processors have no way of knowing whether anything they process came from a `CDATA` section; as far as they know, any `CDATA` content is just plain text. As such, when jQuery processes `CDATA` stuff, it isn't going to treat it any differently than stuff that appeared in a string literal (in fact, since jQuery is simply a layer over the `DOM`, it has absolutely no way of knowing whether its input came from a `CDATA` section or a string literal, since the `DOM` doesn't make any such distinction).

Comment: That's a good pill of knowledge full of sense, thank you for the info, then I should change my question on, how can I insert HTML inside an XML in order to be understood as HTML by Jquery?